# Performance optimization in R

Tags: r

I am starting out with R and needed to write a function to calculate `(false positive, true positive)`pairs given probability response of a binary classifier and the ground truth. I came up with below function initially:

```
calc2=function(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)
{   
    type1 = classes[1]
    type2 = classes[2]
    n=length(response)
    tpden = 0
    fpden = 0
    fp = 0
    tp = 0
    for(i in 1:n)
    {   
        predicted = ifelse(response[i]<threshold,type1,type2)
        actual = groundTruth[i]
        if (actual == type1)
        {
            fpden = fpden + 1
            if (predicted != actual)
            {
                fp = fp + 1
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tpden = tpden + 1
            if (predicted == actual)
            {
                tp = tp + 1
            }
        }       
    }
    fp = fp/fpden
    tp = tp/tpden       
    return(c(fp,tp))
}
```

this function is **100x** slower than below:

```
calc=function(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)
{
    type1 = classes[1]
    type2 = classes[2]
    n=length(response)
    predicted = as.factor(ifelse(response<threshold,type1,type2))
    I = which(groundTruth==type1)
    fp = length(which(predicted[I] != type1)) / length(I)
    I = which(groundTruth==type2)
    tp = length(which(predicted[I] == type2)) / length(I)
    return(c(fp,tp))
}

> benchmark(calc(response,groundTruth,classes,threshold), calc2(response,groundTruth,classes,threshold),replications=10)
                                              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  calc(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)           10    0.14    1.000      0.14        0         NA        NA
2 calc2(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)           10   13.06   93.286     13.05        0         NA        NA
```

**Question: can calc be made even faster?**

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good Code Review question?

Comment: i didn't realize that. could someone migrate this to code reviews stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a littler faster... not sure why you were calculating n.

```
calc=function(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)
{
    type1 = classes[1]
    type2 = classes[2]
    predicted = as.factor(ifelse(response<threshold,type1,type2))
    I = groundTruth==type1
    fp = sum(predicted[I] != type1) / sum(I)
    I = groundTruth==type2
    tp = sum(predicted[I] == type2) / sum(I)
    return(c(fp,tp))
}
```

Some assumptions could make it even faster... like that there's only the two types possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the inefficient `ifelse` statement.

```
calc <- function(response, groundTruth, classes, threshold)
{
  type1 <- classes[1]
  type2 <- classes[2]
  predicted <- rep(type2, length(response))
  predicted[response<threshold] <- type1
  I <- groundTruth==type1
  fp <- sum(predicted[I] != type1) / sum(I)
  I <- groundTruth==type2
  tp <- sum(predicted[I] == type2) / sum(I)
  return(c(fp,tp))
}
```